# Why do we place a series resistor in the MISO signal of an SPI interface? What is the purpose of the and exact functionality of the series resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, resistors, circuit-design, embedded

I am working on a project in which I have to connect a 50R resistor in series in with the MISO signal line of a SPI interface.

My searches tell me it is used to match the impedance as well as attenuate the noise,  but I still need more clarity.

Since I am in progress of learning, I would like know it clearly so that it will be helpful for my knowledge.

Comment: Can you add more details, like schematics, devices used with the SPI interface ? As is your question is a bit vague ... like explain why do you "have to connect a 50K resistor in series" ? Is this because you were told to do so, or you read it some where ... more details so we can understand your dilema please ...

Comment: Did you mean to write 50K (50 kΩ)? It's an unusually high value for the purpose of protection.

Comment: Do you have to connect it because it doesn't work without it? Please show a schematic.

Comment: A 50 kohm resistor in series will usually not make any sense, unless there is a reason for it which could be obvious of you told which chips are being used. Show the schematics and used chips

Comment: Thanks for your Comments , kindly Excuse me , Typing Mistake instead of 50 R i types 50 K. So it is 50 Ohm resistor , I will edit the question now

Comment: The second question is, where it is placed on the circuit, is the resistor on MISO is placed on MCU MISO input or on slave MISO output?

Comment: 50R is 1000 orders of magnitude smaller, so yeaaaas that makes a big difference ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50k seems high, 50 ohms is more reasonable...

Modern logic families have very strong output drivers and can produce signals with edge rise and fall times in the nanosecond region. This is often undesirable unless you want to have to analyse all of your PCB traces as RF transmission lines which is a pain in the arse.

We solve this by adding a little series resistance at the sending end of the line, such that it both absorbs the reflections and slows down the rise and fall times by forming an RC filter.

Sometimes you see a pair of 15 ohm or so resistors right where a line splits, there serve a similar purpose but help to dampen the resonance due to the T structure, this is often seen in single ended clocks.

Howard Johnson wrote one of the better books on this stuff, "High speed signal propagation - Advanced black magic", worth the read.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely 50 ohms, matching the line impedance.  Line impedance is the impedance you'd get to see when measuring an infinitely long line, one where the other end is so far away that you never get to interact with it.

By closing the line off with the line impedance, it becomes indistinguishable from an infinite line, which means that there are no reflections or other artifacts of the line ending.  This is of little relevance when the line length is very short compared to the wavelength of the signals traveling along it.  But part of the signals may be its edges and those are comparatively high-frequency compared to the rest and you don't want them reflected/distorted either.